# preg_replace not replacing everything

Tags: php, preg-replace

im trying to get preg_replace to totally remove a string from a message

heres an example of a $message:

```
hello there john214

welcome to the site!

please get feel free to kick back and relax.
```

where `john214` is a username outputted via the db

now i want to get rid of `hello there john214` using preg_replace, however, my code is removing everything except for `john214`

heres my code:

```
$message = preg_replace('|hello there (.*?)|si', '', $message);
```

why is it not removing `john214`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be because you are doing a non greedy approach.  Try this:

```
$message = preg_replace('|hello there(.*)|si', '', $message);
```

This will get rid of **EVERYTHING** that goes after `hello there` (because of the [S modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)).  However, if what you want is get rid of everything in a **single line** that goes after `hello there`, you want to get rid of the `s` modifier as:

```
$message = preg_replace('|hello there(.*)|i', '', $message);
```

If you use the s modifier you are making the [Dot metacharacter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) to match newlines, and that's why the first regex will consume all what goes after hello there (even jumping to new lines).

Comment: Note that until the *end of the string* is not the same as *the end of the line* with the `s` modifier.

Comment: i figured it out: `preg_replace('|hello there (.*?)(\s)|si', '', $message);`

Comment: you want to remove the `s` modifier. that will make the `.*` include newlines which will go to the end of the string instead of end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

get rid of ? and of "s":

```
$message = preg_replace('~hello there .*~i', '', $message);
```

also, "|" is a poor choice for a delimiter, since "|" is special in the regexp language

Comment: Totally agree with the "|" delimiter.